# Xamarin iOS: Random crashing when launching app on 7.1

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monodevelop

After updating to the 7.1 SDK, my app will sometimes (appears to be random) crash to the home screen immediately after launching. This happens on the simulator and the device. I haven't been able to reproduce this at all on the 7.0.3 SDK. When debugging on the device, there are no error messages received when this happens. The app will crash to the home screen and the last line in the Application Output on Xamarin will read:

```
Launching /private/var/mobile/Applications/7840DFD4-9B41-4DA5-86FB-CBBF37A03BB2/MyApp.app -debugtrack -monodevelop-port 10000 -connection-mode usb
```

On the device, if I try to launch the app again by tapping the icon, it will keep crashing out to the home screen. However, if I delete the app and re-deploy it will usually work and then I can open and close the app without any crashes. On the simulator, after the initial app crash I can relaunch the app by tapping the icon on the home screen and it will work without issue.

I've checked the System Log after a crash and compared it to the System Log with no crash. The only difference is the following four lines:

```
SpringBoard[8050] <Warning>: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image
SpringBoard[8050] <Warning>: SMS Plugin initialized.
SpringBoard[8050] <Warning>: Sharing Plugin initialized.
SpringBoard[8050] <Warning>: SIMToolkit plugin for SpringBoard initialized.
```

These lines don't show up at all during a successful launch, but will show up every single time I get the immediate crash described above. I'm really having a difficult time tracking down the reason for this, as like I said it only happens on 7.1. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you pastebin the crash reports from the device/simulator?

Comment: @Rolf Thank you for the reply. Here is the dump: http://pastebin.com/j0x2asPZ

Comment: What kinds of things are you doing in your FinishedLaunching() method inside of your app delegate class?

Comment: @NovaJoe Nothing at all. The only thing in there is 'return true'.

Comment: Weird. Yeah, that's a pretty clean FinishedLaunching method.